# Does using noatime on modern Linux make sense?

Tags: linux

Starting from version 2.6.30 (which was released 5 years ago), Linux has the option `relatime` enabled by default. It means updates of file access time are very infrequent and prudent.

But I still see [recomendations](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/tuning-disks-and-linux-for-postgres/) to use `noatime` for databases or SSD discs. Are there any reason to use it? Does it make any measurable difference compared to `relatime`?

Comment: Do you care about tracking access time of database files? If not, use `noatime`, I think it's that simple.

Comment: @mustaccio use default configuration simpler

Comment: I never look at last access time of database files as these are being constantly accessed anyway!